# accelerate Make based builds and "Build Server" solutions

Tags: build, jenkins, makefile

This is my first time posting here so I hope I will be coherent and provide all the required info for you folks to understand my point.

Inside my company we use a make based build, in all projects. Different versions of compilers are used from one project to another (but I guess this is not an issue).

====> My goal is somehow to implement first of all a solution that will reduce build times (not by using the -j option) by a factor at "3" for example. The resources to accomplish this to be the CPU's of the other computers in the network (around 200 PC all multicore CPU's).

After this to create some nightly builds, and other reporting and automation but I think with Jenkins should be no issue.

Projects at this point built on a computer last form 15min to 180min for a clean build. Also all the source file and make process (all the information) is stored in a SCM system

So my question to you: 
- do you have an idea of what software to use to accelerate builds? (opensource would be the way to go for me so that implementation costs should be minimal). (I know about incredibuild and openmake master, Electric Accelerator) -- but all of the cost, and the 2 open source alternatives (from SUSE and the other that I can't remember now -- I seen only support gcc)

- to automate builds Jenkins is the way I think I should go. Do you agree with this? Do you have other solutions?

Thank you all

Comment: You need accelerate build projects in general? Ccache or distcc programs does not fit?

Comment: What's wrong with the `-j` option?

Answer (score 0):

There's always the ElectricAccelerator Huddle version. Limited to the cores on up to 8 desktops on your team, but that can result in some blazing fast builds if you configure it correctly...